# Need to launch mongod using launchctl

Tags: mongodb, osx-elcapitan, launch-daemon, launch-agent

I have installed `MongoDB` using manual option.

When I fire mongod it will take parameters from somewhere else specially for `dbPath`.

I want to have my own `dbPath` without specifying it with --dbPath each time.

So I found option to provide `mongod.conf` file and call `mongod --config` option but still I need to pass path of `.conf` file.

My ultimate goal is to just launch mongod as service and it will read config file from path I configured. For this I tried `LaunchAgent` and `LaunchDaemon` with no luck. What I thought is that if I can configure `LaunchAgent` or Daemon then I will  provide path to mongod of bin directory of MongoDB folder and provide `--config` and path for `.conf` file as argument and then I need to just launch mongod using `launchctl` with name mongod and it will start `mongod --config <.conf file path>`.

But I am not able to do so. I read nearly 15-16 posts on LaunchAgent and Daemon but did not get solution my problem. I tried to do so with making mongod.plist file at various places like `/Library/LaunchDaemon`, `/Library/LaunchAgent` and `~/Library/LaunchDaemon` but I always get error "`Path had bad ownership/permissions`". I tried `chown` and `chgrp` but no luck.

I hope you got my point. I really need complete solution to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use linux or windows? 
This is the default location of mongodb.conf in linux:

```
/etc/mongodb.conf
```

You can simply edit it with your parameters, and start the service using:

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

If you are using windows, it depends on the version of MongoDB you are using, but check in:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\...
```

For the same file.